# Confused with cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to figure out cookies with JS and I am totally lost, it is so much easier with PHP. I have this line of code could someone explain to me what it means?

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires) {  
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/" + ((expires == null) ? "" : ";      
expires=" + expires.toGMTString()); 
}
```

Comment: Really I am trying to learn and we are taking points off the rep! at least give some advice here. I dont understand what ""=" + escape(value) + "; path=/" + ((expires == null) ? "" : ";      
expires=" + expires.toGMTString()); " means or how it works

Comment: They are confusing the work with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie has a JavaScript object that wraps document.cookie for simple access like GetCookie('chocolateChip'), etc

Comment: Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp for information about the escape function. As for the rest, get a good JS book or run through the tutorials found on the site (http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Comment: @JW01 I'd avoid using w3school as a resource. They are notorious for having incorrect information in their tutorials. You're better off looking else where for examples and reference materials. (like quirksmode.org mentioned below)

Comment: So does the      name + "=" + escape(value) handle the name=value pairing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies have several parts many of them optional

```
 Tokens: name=value ;expires=date ;domain=domain ;path=path
```

`escape(value)`

Escape non alphanumeric characters such as spaces and special characters and 
replaces them with there hexadecimal equilivments 
like %hh, A space would would be `%20`

path=/"  A subset of paths at domain "/" everything from and beneath the first path

path=/users/  eg to access it you would need to be in the /users/

`+ ((expires == null) ? "" : "` ; `expires=" + expires.toGMTString())`;

`?: oporator` 
(expression) ? if-true-statement : if-false-statement;

?: oporator can be used whare an `if cannot`

`dose (expires equal null) ?`

// cookies that are set without the expires field are called session cookies.

`( if true set empty string "" )` 
  `else`

// set the token expires width the date

`( if not null set the expires token)`

Answer (score 3):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html has more information...

the `+` in JS is equivalent to `.` in PHP (concatenates)...so you're building a string from the inputs, and formatting the various pieces accordingly (like converting `expires`)

then, document.cookie={that string} sets it

Comment: so why are we concatenating the = and so many ;'s in one line of code and why so many quote symbols?

Comment: the quotes separate the text pieces you're concatenating (the parts without quotes are variable names). The red = in your function are just text (since they're inside quotes)...the == is a ternary operator (a concise if statement) which is testing whether `expires` is null (just like PHP)...that's also why there's the extra semi-colon (finishing up the ternary)

Comment: more...so, as you see on that link, the format of a cookie is `document.cookie =
  'ppkcookie1=testcookie; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'` so, the PHP equivalent would be something like `echo "document.cookie='".$name."=".$value."; expires=".gmdate($expires)."; path=/'";`

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation to your code

`document.cookie` accept a string of the form `key=value` to set the cookie.
A reference could be find from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie)

> cookie attribute values can optionally follow the key-value pair, specifying the cookie to set/update, and **preceded by a semi-colon separator**:

According to this specification, this string should be `name=value ;expires=date ;domain=domain ;path=path`

In your case, the `+` operator behaves the same like `.` operator in PHP. It performs **string concaction**.

```
var b = 'I' + ' am' + ' a' + ' JavaScript' +' hacker.'
>>'I am a JavaScript hacker.'
```

### A Better Solution

To ease your pain, I suggest using the [`jquery.cookie` plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

To set a cookie

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

To get a cookie

```
$.cookie('the_cookie');
```

To delete the cookie

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', null);
```